# clear function for Stanford iOS 8 Calculator application

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am following the Stanford iOS 8 lectures and I believe I have successfully added the "Clear" functionality to the application, but I don't know if I am doing it properly.  My code is as follows:

**Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
.
.
.
// Linked to the "C" button in the Storyboard
@IBAction func clear()
{
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
    brain.clear()
    displayValue = 0
.
.
.
```

**Model**

```
class CalculatorBrain
.
.
.
func evaluate() -> Double?
{
    let (result, remainder) = evaluate(opStack)
    println("\(opStack) = \(result) with \(remainder) left over")
    return result
}

func clear()
{
    opStack = [Op]()
    evaluate()
}
.
.
.
```

And my log output is

```
[8.0] = Optional(8.0) with [] left over
[8.0, 9.0] = Optional(9.0) with [8.0] left over
[8.0, 9.0, ×] = Optional(72.0) with [] left over
[8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0] = Optional(2.0) with [8.0, 9.0, ×] left over
[8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −] = Optional(70.0) with [] left over
[8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −, 5.0] = Optional(5.0) with [8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −] left over
[8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −, 5.0, ÷] = Optional(14.0) with [] left over
[] = nil with [] left over
```

I am pretty sure the last line in the log output is correct.  Basically I was just hoping someone with more iOS/MVC experience could tell me whether or not I implemented the "Clear" functionality correctly.  If I didn't, how might I got about fixing my code?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: You should post this question in code review section.

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't use this site too often.  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Go to `Code Review` http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site and post the same question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made the clear function like this

```
@IBAction func clear(sender: UIButton) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioSound)
    arrayDigit.removeAll()
    arrayOp.removeAll()
    display.text = "0" //displayStack() // remove !
    displayValue = 0
    equal()
}
```